# Yii2 Advance not update data after save file to remote server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm used Yii2 Advance to develop system via remote server. When I save file editor will upload it to server automatic. After save I refresh browser. It's still show old data not update from new file. And about 1 min it will up to date.

I test the different folder on server It's work find, Update when save file.

Please help me.

Thanks and best regards,

Woody

Comment: Let me try to decrypt that question. You update something on your server and can verify that it's actually updated but when you request it from the server (via http?) you get the old result? Checked / cleared all caches?

Comment: That correct decryption. I cleared all caches and try to change browser but not solve the problem.

Comment: What sort of file is it and how do you serve it?

Comment: Every file in Yii2 project need about 1 min to update. I use FTP remote file and edit then save. It's will automatic upload to server.

Comment: **After the upload has finished** you still need to wait a minute for the changes to take effect? Where's your stuff hosted? Is it your own server? Do they have some sort of CDN?

Comment: Yes my own server. In other folder on my server. I don't need to wait. Its normal save and up to date. Only in Yii2 project make me crazy.

Comment: Sure you checked **all the caches**? Client-side / proxy and server-side? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Now I can solve this problem by myself. 
This effect is PHP function "OPCache" it come with PHP 5.5 or higher.

We can disable OPCache by many way but I used this solution.

Open *autoload.php* from /yii2project/vender/autoload.php and add this code.

> opcache_reset();

I don't know what the best way in Yii2 for reset opcache like this. If it has please reply this post.

Thank you everyone and to think this topic will help you.